# URLS Redirects with Cypress automation

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, js-fancyproductdesigner, cypress-component-test-runner

I passed 100+ URLs path(legacy) in the scenario outlines and i want to hit each one of them and to redirect to a new path(new).
I passed a code like below;

```
function createNewUrlFromLegacy(legacyPageUrl) {
  const urlPath = legacyPageUrl.split('/');
let newUrl;

if (urlPath.length == 7) {
    newUrl = 'new-homes/' + urlPath[5];
 } else {
    newUrl = 'new-homes/' + urlPath[0];
} 
    return newUrl        
}
```

I passed this following in my stepDef file

```
const expectedUrl = createNewUrlFromLegacy(legacyUrl);
 cy.url().should('include', expectedUrl);
```

And it run successfully.

But i want to use response code 301 as an assertion instead relying on expectedUrl only.

How can i do this pls?.

Comment: Have you tried if cypress will allow you to visit them since they need to be on the same domain? What do you need to validate - the redirect? correct page content? etc

Comment: @RosenMihaylov Yes, Cypress allowed me, i want to validate response code. See the above for update pls. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get it working using the following steps;
First visit the legacy url and then set followRedirects: false using alias.

cy.visit(legacyUrl);

cy.request({url: legacyUrl, followRedirect: false}).as('response');`
cy.get('@response').its('status').should('eq', 301); --> Assert Response code is 301
cy.get('@response').its('redirectedToUrl').should('contain', expectedUrl); -->Assert expected URL is displayed.